# Find all solutions of the differential equation $y' = 3|y|^{2/3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a HS student self studying differential equations and ran into this practice problem:

> Find all solutions of the differential equation $y' = 3|y|^{2/3}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

I have never encountered absolute values and am a little lost. Any help with this problem would be great, I know I can use Wolfram Alpha to check the answer but I would like to learn how it is solved. I keep getting $y = (x + C)^3$ with $y(0) = C^3$.

Comment: @Arthur : here you can't apply the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem because $f:x\mapsto 3|x|^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not locally-lipschitz, so I can't see how you can say that $y$ never changes sign ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean @Baloown

Comment: sorry if I am not clear, I asked Arthur how does he can say that a solution doesn't vanish without the use of Cauchy-Lipschit's  theorem (and the fact that $y\mapsto 0$ is solution), perhaps it is more known as Picard-Lindelöf theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to notice is that $y=0$ is a solution. Always check for equilibrium solutions when solving separable equations: they are frequently lost when one divides by an expression with $y$ that may be zero.

So far, we have $y=0$ and $y=(x+C)^3$. Drawing these, you should see the unusual feature of these solutions: the cubic polynomials cross the line $y=0$. This makes it possible to create more solutions by pasting together pieces of these: go along the cubic, then along the line, then again along the cubic. The complete family of solutions can be described as
$$
y(x) = \begin{cases} (x-a)^3 \quad &\text{if  } x\le a\\
0 & \text{if }a< x< b \\ 
(x-b)^3 &\text{if } x\ge b\end{cases}
$$
where $-\infty\le a\le b\le \infty$.

When $a$ or $b$ are infinite, certain clauses are never fulfilled: e.g., if $a=-\infty$ and $b=1$, we just have $y(x)=0$ for $x<1$ and $y(x)=(x-1)^3$ for $x\ge 1$.